# Using ggplot2 (R) to color individual datapoints in boxplot by repeat

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to show data from an experiment that has been repeated x-number of times using a boxplot. I would like to show each individual data point. In addition, to help people understand the effect of individual repeats, I would like to color the data points according to the repeat.
The following code works, but it does not allow me to color the data points.
As always any help is appreciated

sample data and code below

```
  #   conditions    repeats fold
  #  A  1   7.11415E-05
  #  B  1   0.094383838
  #  C  1   2.13914E-05
  #  D  1   1
  #  E  1   0.418905744
  #  F  1   0.62318476
  #  A  2   0.00069782
  #  B  2   0.006064881
  #  C  2   0.00090097
  #  D  2   1
  #  E  2   1.198034711
  #  F  2   1.20836637

library(ggplot2)

# Load data file from current working directory:
data <- read.delim("data_example.txt",header=T,sep="\t")
data
data$conditions <- factor(data$conditions,levels=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))

cbbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

ggplot(data, aes(conditions, fold, hue=repeats)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0) + 
  geom_jitter( aes(conditions, fold),
              position=position_jitter(width=0,height=0),
              alpha=1,
              size=3,
              show_guide=FALSE) +
  ylab("Y-AXIS") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face='bold',size=16,vjust=1),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face='bold',size=12,color='black'),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face='bold',size=14,color='black'),
        legend.position="none")
```

edit:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(conditions = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
"F"), class = "factor"), repeats = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), fold = c(7.11415e-05, 0.094383838, 2.13914e-05, 
1, 0.418905744, 0.62318476, 0.00069782, 0.006064881, 0.00090097, 
1, 1.198034711, 1.20836637)), .Names = c("conditions", "repeats", 
"fold"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

edit 2:

my code gives:

[image]

adding "col=factor(repeats)" gives:
[image]

what I would like is (and if possible, allow me to control the colors):
[image]

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(data)` at the end of your question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Is `aes(color = factor(repeats))` within `geom_jitter` all you need?

Comment: I added some visual examples...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I want...

```
library(ggplot2)

# Load data file from current working directory:
data <- read.delim("data_example.txt",header=T,sep="\t")

data$conditions <- factor(data$conditions,levels=c("luciferase","HPV18 E6-E7","luciferase + Dox","HPV18 E6-E7 + Dox","HPV18 E6TTL-E7 + Dox","HPV18 E6-E7TTL + Dox"))

cbbPalette <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

ggplot(data, aes(conditions, fold)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size=0, width = 0.3) + 
  geom_dotplot( aes(fill=factor(repeats)),
                binaxis='y', 
                stackdir='center',
                alpha=1,
                dotsize=0.5) +
  ylab("fold E6*I mRNA level") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face='bold',size=16,vjust=1),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face='bold',size=12,color='black',angle = 90, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face='bold',size=14,color='black'),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbbPalette) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Biological repeats")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1.2, by = 0.2), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, linetype="dashed", color = "red")
```

[image]